# Does Hawking Radiation Violate General Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, astrophysics

“Electromagnetic radiation which, according to theory, should be emitted by a black hole. The radiation is due to the black hole capturing one of a particle-antiparticle pair created spontaneously near to the event horizon.” (General definition of Hawking Radiation)

I have several questions concerning this…..

Once one of the virtual particles is swallowed by the by the event horizon, the surviving particle becomes a real particle.  The generally accepted theory is that the black hole provides the energy needed to allow this to happen.  Wouldn’t any energy syphoned from the singularity need to travel faster than light to achieve this?  I mean light cannot escape the black hole as it cannot travel faster than C.  This means that any energy from the singularity has to first escape the massive gravity field / warped space time.  It also has to travel the distance from the singularity to through the event horizon to the particle nearly instantaneously.  How is this possible?  This would appear to violate General Relativity wouldn't it?

Why are not both particles drawn into the black hole?  If the virtual particles pop into existence so close to each other to be instantly annihilated by each other, shouldn’t they both be pulled in?

Can the antiparticle half of the virtual particle pairs be pulled into the black hole?  Does the black hole lose mass equal to antiparticle mass?

Comment: Hi Rick. The "two particles" is just an analogy and not what actually happens. I've linked to an explanation of what is actually going on.

Comment: Rule 1: Don't use virtual particles as a tool to explain any physical process, if you plan to do it rigorously (and correctly).